# Dereference Operator Before an Array Element?

Tags: c

What does the notation in something like `int y = *x[0]` do, i.e. when you have a dereference operator right before an array element?

Comment: It dereferences the pointer that's in `x[0]`.

Answer (score 5):

The postfix operator `[]` binds stronger than the prefix operator `*`, and more generally all postfix operators bind stronger than all prefix operators. Hence `*x[0]` is equivalent to `*(x[0])` which can occur and have type `int` in different cases:

- if `x` is an array of arrays of `int`, also known as a 2D array of `int`: `int x[2][2];`
- if `x` is an array of pointers to `int`: `int *x[2];`
- if `x` is a pointer to a pointer to `int`: `int **x;`
- if `x` is a pointer to an array of `int`: `int (*x)[2];` (this one is very confusing)

For all of the above, the expression `*x[0]` is equivalent to any of these:

- `x[0][0]`
- `**x`
- and by coincidence `(*x)[0]`

As well as these unusual and surprising expressions:

- `0[*x]`
- `0[x[0]]`
- `0[0[x]]`
- `*0[x]`
- `0[x][0]`

Answer (score 1):

The array subscript operator has higher precedence than the dereference operator, so `*x[0]` dereferences element 0 of the array `x`.  This would make sense if you had an array of pointers, i.e. `int *x[10]`.

Comment: It also makes sense if `x` is a two dimensional array of `int` :)

Answer (score 1):

`*expr` is like `expr[0]` with the `[0]` at the very end of `expr`.
`[subscript]` binds tighter than unary `*`.

That makes `*x[1]` equivalent to `x[1][0]`, and if it evaluates to an `int`,
then `x` could have been either an array of pointers or a two-dimensional `int` array.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    {
        //two dimensional int-array
        int x[2][2]={
            {1,2},
            {3,4},
        };
        printf("%d\n", *x[1]); //3
        printf("%d\n", x[1][0 /*the star*/]); //3
    }
    {
        //array of pointers to int
        int *x[2] = { &(int){1}, &(int){2} };
        printf("%d\n", *x[1]); //2
        printf("%d\n", x[1][0 /*the star*/]); //2
    }

}
```

Comment: You might also mention that `*x[0]` is equivalent to `**x`

Answer (score 0):

this will only make sense if you have an array of pointers to intgers :

```
 int var = *x[0]
```

means that x is a table of pointers and var will take the value pointed by the first element (pointer) in this array

Comment: As can be read in the previous answers, it also makes sense if `x` is a two dimensional array of `int` such as `int x[2][2];`

Answer (score -3):

You forgot to specify an identifier:)

```
int = *x[0]
```

Should be something like

```
int value = *x[0]
```

Pay attention to that this expression `*x[0]` is equivalent to the expression `*( x[0] )` because the postfix subscript operator has a higher precedence than the unary operator *.
It is evident that such a construction is used when x denotes an array of pointers or a pointer to an object of a pointer type.

That is when the type of the expression `x[0]` is a pointer type. So you may apply to such an expression the dereferncing operator.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int plus( int x, int y )
{
    return ( long long int )x + y;
}

long long int minus( int x, int y )
{
    return ( long long int )x - y;
}

int main(void) 
{
    long long int ( *fp[] )( int, int ) = { plus, minus };
    int x = 10, y = 5;

    unsigned long long result = ( *fp[0] )( x, y );

    printf( "x + y = %lld\n", result );

    result = ( *fp[1] )( x, y );

    printf( "x - y = %lld\n", result );

    int a1[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int a2[]  = { 4, 5, 6 };

    int * a[] = { a1, a2 };

    int value = *a[1];

    printf( "value = %d\n", value );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
x + y = 15
x - y = 5
value = 4
```

Such a constriction like

```
int = *x[0]
```

without an identifier you can meet in a C++ program. Such constructions are used to specify a default argument for a function parameter.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int a[][2] = 
{
    { 10, 20 },
    { 30, 40 }
};  

int ( *x )[2] = a;

void f( int = *x[0] );

void f( int value )
{
    std::cout << "value = " << value << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
value = 10
```

Comment: The question is tagged `c`, not `c++`, and your example is unnecessarily contrived

Comment: @chqrlie You are wrong. I showed where such a construction without an identifier can be met. So the example is very useful.

Comment: The first example is convoluted: why introduce an array of function pointers? The second example is C++ specific, whereas the OP probably just made a typo and no such construct is possible in C.

Comment: @chqrlie Even he is made a typo it is interesting to know that nevertheless such a construction can be used in a language that is very close to C.

Comment: OK for that, but such a find belongs in a comment, it is off topic in an answer as it refers to a different language :) Not to mention the deluge of criticism a c++ programmer would get for defining a global variable named `x`.

Comment: Another way to make this construct possible in C is to `#define int long y`... which is UB as well.

Comment: @chqrlie The program demonstrates only the construction. There is nothing to do by "your  C++ programmer".

Comment: The error in the question has been corrected. It now says `int y = *x[0]`

Comment: @KeithThompson This does not matter.

Comment: @chqrlie: `#define int long y` is not undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: indeed it is not! good to know for the next OCCC :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Agreed -- except that `#define int long y` can have undefined behavior if it interacts with a standard header. "The program shall not have any macros with names lexically identical to keywords currently defined prior to the inclusion of the header or when any macro defined in the header is expanded." (That probably doesn't apply to the code under discussion.)